# raising a softirq in assembly x86 or ARM

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, arm

I am familiar with the [instruction `int` on x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_%28x86_instruction%29).

1. Is it possible to inline assembly `int my_unique_number` and use
   `requst_irq(my_unique_number , function);` with a function to be
   called when the instruction is executed?
2. What about ARM is there any similar way to use [`SWI immed_8` instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/BABFCEEG.html) or [SVC](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0290g/ch02s08s13.html)?
3. Can I do the same trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Linux kernel it's much simpler to simply implement your own system call in the kernel and use the `syscall(your_number)` function to call it rather than doing the assembly code yourself.

Doing so is very easy http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3326 here's a link to an article that describes how to do so in much less words than I would have used.

Comment: @0x90 Do you want to have it run when a particular interrupt happens or just in certain cases where you will call `request_irq`. If so why not just call the function directly (unless you need atomic context)?

Comment: @0x90 If you're in atomic context you can't raise an interrupt because an interrupt itself is atomic. You can always disable interrupts via `spin_lock_irqsave` and `spin_unlock_irqrestore` and then execute your code.